# Getting multiple fields from database to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I wrote an api call in my `Symfony` project that returns all fields from my entity with the query defined below..

Now, I need to define just three fields like 'id', 'name', 'value' and to pull values from that fields that are currently stored in a database.

```
public function getChartData() {
    $myResults = $this->getMyRepository()
                       ->createQueryBuilder('s')
                       ->groupBy('s.totalCollected')
                       ->orderBy('s.id', 'ASC')
                       ->getQuery()
                       ->getArrayResult();

    $result = array("data" => array());

    foreach ($myResults as $myResult => $label) {
            $result['data'][$schoolResult] =  $label["id"];
            $result['data'][$schoolResult] =  $label["name"];
            $result['data'][$schoolResult] =  $label["totalCollected"];
    }
}
```

The problem is it return just `totalCollected` field.

One of errors are Call to a member function `getId()` on array and so on, and I can't figure out a way to pull data from db...

Comment: You are returning an array of data from the DB. So in order to access it you will need to use some loop `for` `foreach` or `while` or use `0` as an access to a first item in that array. If you are using 0 than something like this might help `$myResults[0]->getId(),`

Comment: so, you cannot use array as an object, I assume you get an array back with single/multiple rows, I think you should iterate it and then, get your fields from each row and a single row should match your entity

Comment: Can you share the content of `$myResults` and `$schoolResults`?

Comment: I edited the post it actually the same. I get response just for last array of values. Just totalCollected is returned, not Id and Name.. @DavidWinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see in your code where `$schoolResult` come from but lets guess it string key of some sort.

Notice you trying to set 3 value on the same key so only the last one remains.

Look at:

```
$a = array();
$a["key"] = 4;
$a["key"] = 6;
```

It is simple to see that `$a["key"]` will contains 6 and not 4 or both.

When you do:

```
foreach ($myResults as $myResult => $label) {
    $result['data'][$schoolResult] =  $label["id"];
    $result['data'][$schoolResult] =  $label["name"];
    $result['data'][$schoolResult] =  $label["totalCollected"];
}
```

You override the data in `$result['data'][$schoolResult]` therefor only try `totalCollected` is there as the last one to set.

In order to fix that you can use:

```
foreach ($myResults as $myResult => $label) {
    $result['data'][$schoolResult]["id] =  $label["id"];
    $result['data'][$schoolResult]["name"] =  $label["name"];
    $result['data'][$schoolResult]["totalCollected"] =  $label["totalCollected"];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot! @DavidWinder